# Order by clause in update query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to update table using order by clause in sql server 2008 e.g

```
Update tblTempChek Set TmpCheckIn='15:50:03' 
Where TempID IN (
    Select TempID 
    From tblTempChek 
    Where convert(date, TmpDate)='2015-06-23' AND UserID='1' 
    Order By TempID Desc
)
```

but this gives error

```
    Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
    The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Comment: The question is: why?

Comment: it is just requirement to update tblTempChek

Comment: Update a table using an order by doesn't make sense.

Comment: sir i need order by in select statement

Comment: Why does the order by need to be in the subquery at all?

Comment: You need to rethink your query strategy.

Comment: in select statement table have many record with respect to mentioned date and user id lets suppose 10 but at the time of updation i need last updated record. got the point?

Comment: The answer to the question is already in the error reporting. "invalid in subqueries" , The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use TOP:

```
    Update tblTempChek Set TmpCheckIn='15:50:03' 
    Where TempID in (
        Select TOP 1 TempID 
        From tblTempChek 
        Where Convert(date, TmpDate)='2015-06-23' AND UserID='1'
        Order By TempID Desc
    )
```

Comment: I dont think so. I have tried it. Have you?

Comment: this works for me. I just forget this bloody " top " in my query. Thanks.

Comment: It will not fail but why OP has IN clause then?

Comment: Good catch...he was missing `TOP`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use max, such as:

```
Update tblTempChek Set TmpCheckIn='15:50:03' 
Where TempID IN (
    Select MAX(TempID) 
    From tblTempChek 
    Where convert(date, TmpDate)='2015-06-23' AND UserID='1'
)
```

This assuming the TempID is some incrementing value.